# Pylint Report Generation

Tags: pylint

How can you get pylint to print a report?  My response only tells the errors and the score.
This is my response,

```
************* Module main
PycharmProjects\turtle_race\main.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
PycharmProjects\turtle_race\main.py:4:0: C0103: Constant name "on" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
PycharmProjects\turtle_race\main.py:27:4: C0103: Constant name "on" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
PycharmProjects\turtle_race\main.py:32:12: C0103: Constant name "on" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.86/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +8.86)
```

I tried typing `pylint --ry` but it gave an error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command line option to create a report in pylint is:

```
pylint -r y <file>
```

or

```
pylint -ry <file>
```